# Add subversion revision to war manifest using maven2

Tags: java, maven-2, build-automation, war

I want to find a maven native (i.e. without calling external programs) to inject the svn revision in the war manifest.

Does anybody know a way to do that?

I found mention to how to add the subversion revision to manifests in jar files but not with war files.

I searched SO but could not find this issue specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to find a maven native (i.e. without calling external programs) to inject the svn revision in the war manifest.

This is possible with the [Build Number Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) using the `svnjava` provider:

> If you need to execute the plugin on
>   machine without any svn in the path
>   you can configure the mojo to use the
>   svnjava provider.
>
> ```
>   <build>
>     <plugins>
>       <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>         <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
>         <executions>
>           <execution>
>             <phase>validate</phase>
>             <goals>
>               <goal>create</goal>
>             </goals>
>           </execution>
>         </executions>
>         <configuration>
>           <doCheck>true</doCheck>
>           <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
>           <providerImplementations>
>             <svn>javasvn</svn>
>           </providerImplementations>          
>         </configuration>
>       </plugin>
>     </plugins>
>   </build>
> ```

The Build Number Maven Plugin sets the build number in the `${buildNumber}` property that you can then use in your POM.

> I found mention to how to add the subversion revision to manifests in jar files but not with war files.

Then, to add the build number in the MANIFEST of a war, configure the plugin as mentioned in the [Usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) page:

```
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html). About halfway down, look for maven-war-plugin

```
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```